# Bootstrap menu disappears onclick on mobile / & header image wont resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, bootstrap-4

So I spent a few hours trying to solve this myself, with the help of other people's posts but had no luck. Allow me to explain my issues first.

My website, [www.discoverbugs.org](http://www.discoverbugs.org), has a bootstrap navigation menu. It looks fine on the desktop, but on mobile, the drop-down menu disappears when you click on it. What's causing it and how can I fix it?

The second issue is the header image. On mobile, it expands across the entire width of the phone. I'm having this issue with a lot of images on the site. I tried adding max and min widths and it just won't work for me. Can someone please help me edit this? It looks ridiculous.

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) { header {
padding: 65px 0 0px;  } }
```

Index.php

```
    <header class="bg-primary text-white">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <img src="img/header-v6.jpg">
  </div>
</header>
```

Header.php (Navigation menu)

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="index.php">Discover Bugs</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="collections.php">Collections</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="form.php">Costs & Booking</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="faq.php">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Javascript coding I have:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: Bootstrap 3 JavaScript is not designed to work with Bootstrap 4.

In other words, for Bootstrap 4 css you also need Bootstrap 4 JavaScript (as well as jQuery 3.2.1 and popper.js).

To fix the header image issue add the `img-fluid` class to the image like so:

`<img class="img-fluid" src="img/header-v6.jpg">`

This will make the image responsive.

To fix the first issue, use the css and JavaScript files from the following template (and load them in that order):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="index.php">Discover Bugs</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="collections.php">Collections</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="form.php">Costs & Booking</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="faq.php">FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me a lot of time, I really appreciate it